# How to list the last modified files in a specific directory recursively

Tags: command-line, files, search, productivity

It may be a generic Linux question but I'll give it a try here.

I need a list of recently modified files very often and currently for it I am piping `ls` output to `grep` with the param on today or a certain hour, but I need to change the `grep` param frequently to get an updated list,  being a bit unproductive.

Is there an easy command to list the last modified files on a certain path ?

Comment: An existing command not as far as I know. A script would be easy to make. Saved in `$PATH` would make it a command. Is that what you sre looking for?

Comment: yes it could work for me as a script too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To find the last 5 modified files from a certain directory recursively, from that directory run:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1,1nr | head -5
```

- `%T@` with `-printf` predicate of `find` will get modification time since epoch for the files, `%p` will print the file names
- `sort -k1,1nr` will reverse numerically `sort` the result according to the epoch time
- `head -5` will get us the last modified five file names

If you just want to search only in the current directory (not recursively), use `stat`:

```
stat -c '%Y %n' * | sort -k1,1nr | head -5
```

Or `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1,1nr | head -5
```

Check `man find` and `man stat` to get more idea.

Comment: `find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1,1nr | head -5` gives me error in Azure: `sort: fflush failed: standard output` and `sort: write error`

Comment: Using `%TY-%Tm-%Td-%TH:%TM:%TS` in place of `%T@` produces a more readable output. In that case you also want to omit `-n`.

Answer (score 8):

It is so simple actually.To get the Most recent file in the currant directory:

`ls -Art | tail -n 2`

To get the Most recent file in another directory , for example in  /opt/spark/ :

`ls /opt/spark/ -Art | tail -n 1`

This is when i use it on my cluster:

```
aa23916@picard03:/opt/spark/applicationHistory$ ls -Art | tail -n 2
app-20180124162809-0004
app-20180124163207-0005.inprogress
```

Simple and easy : )

Comment: If you have to explicitly state a folder it hardly seems recursive

Comment: -t already lists newest first, so reversing it gives you the least recently modified file.

Answer (score 6):

The script below lists all files recursively inside a directory, edited shorter ago than an arbitrary time. Additionally, it displays the time span since the last edit.

It can be used with the command:

```
findrecent <directory> <time(in hours)>
```

as shown below:

[image]

In this example, all files on my Desktop, edited less than 36 hours ago are listed.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]

try:
    t = int(sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
    t = 1

currtime = time.time(); t = t*3600

def calc_time(minutes):
    # create neatly displayed time
    if minutes < 60:
        return "[edited "+str(minutes)+" minutes ago]"
    else:
        hrs = int(minutes/60); minutes = int(minutes - hrs*60)
        return "[edited "+str(hrs)+" hours and "+str(minutes)+" minutes ago]"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, file); ftime = os.path.getctime(file)
        edited = currtime - ftime
        if edited < t:
            print(file, calc_time(int(edited/60)))
```

#### How to use

1. Create, if it doesn't exist yet, the directory `~/bin`
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `findrecent` in `~/bin`
3. **Make the script executable**
4. Log out and back in and you're done

#### Note

- if no time is given, the script lists all files, edited in the last hour
- if a directory includes spaces, use quotes, like in the example

Comment: That really seems like overkill (reinventing the wheel) when so many tools already exist that can easily be piped together to do this.  (As heemayl described.)

Comment: @Wildcard Tools, of which `python` is one, or: tools, *used by* python to control them in an easy way. The script was written in a minute into a flexible and easy to use option to list recently used files recursively. No doubt a matter of taste, an ongoing discussion I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

To get last 5 modified files execute the below command in the directory you looking for.

```
ls -lrt | tail -5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [HseJar](https://askubuntu.com/users/1159611/hsejar)'s and [A Alnafessah](https://askubuntu.com/users/786951/a-alnafessah)'s answer

`find /myfolder/ -type f | xargs ls -lt | head`

shows the latest, with a full path (including dates)